# How to get specific child value from a child?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wrote this code to get the values of a user who typed his username and i want to check his password :

```
MyDatabase.child("USERS").orderByChild("username").equalTo(Username.getText().toString())
  .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Log.i("Password",child.getValue().toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

[image: My database]

now i want to access the password field and check if the user entered the correct password or not .

Comment: why you don't use firebase authentication ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve that. The first one is not to let the user leave an empty `EditText` when creating the account. And second is to verify if the `dataSnapshot.exists()`. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
MyDatabase.child("USERS")      
  .orderByChild("username").equalTo(Username.getText().toString())
  .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Log.i("Password",child.child("password").getValue().toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

The changes:

1. `child.child("password").getValue()`
2. don't ignore `onCancelled()`